# Cakephp 3 - Auth Login Return False

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, identify

What's the problem with this code?
The Controller and Identify only return false!
My database column is senha (password) and email. And I can not sign in.
I am using hash, password with 255 characters and all right.
But it's not working!

**ContaController.php**

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['email' => 'email', 'senha' => 'senha'],
                'userModel' => 'Conta',
                'finder' => 'auth',
            ]
        ],
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Conta',
            'action' => 'index',
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Conta',
            'action' => 'minha-agenda'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Conta',
            'action' => 'index',
        ],
        'storage' => 'Memory'
    ]);
    $this->Auth->allow(['index']);
}


public function index() {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax') || $this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            // return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            var_dump($user);
            echo 'incorrect';

        }
    }
}
```

**ContaTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('alunos');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsToMany('Alunos', [
        'foreignKey' => 'interesses_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'alunos_id',
        'joinTable' => 'alunos_interesses'
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('email', 'A username is required')
        ->notEmpty('senha', 'A password is required');
    return $validator;
}

public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options) {
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'email', 'senha'])
        ->where(['Conta.email' => $options['email']])
        ->andWhere(['Conta.senha' => $options['senha']]);
    return $query;
}
```

I need help solving this problem.
The columns in the database are different, so I do not intend to use it as default.
More ahead it will become ajax but for now it is so because I could not solve!

Comment: This site is the StackOverflow English site. To use the Portuguese site, go to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Both Portuguese and English can be solved ... Brazilians and Portuguese do not use this site very much! That's why I wrote in English. Any problems enter the text in Google Translate!

Comment: what is in your .ctp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `'fields' => ['email' => 'email', 'senha' => 'senha']` to `'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'senha']`

With this config, you don't need a custom finder, unless you require to select columns. By using the default finder, you could always unset properties.

Make sure your login form controls and table columns are named `email` and `senha`

Then, I'm wondering if you eighter way should load authcomponent in AppController.